# SSRS Chart Hiding one group if it has 0 value

Tags: ssrs-2008, pie-chart

I have one pie chart that has 4 types. I want to hide the display of the particular group if the total aggregate is 0. [image: Please see the attached image file]. Based on my chart, Could anyone please help me how to  change the filter condition not to show paid group if it has 0. TIA

Answer (score 1):

You can filter by TOTAL in the **Category Group** properties of the chart.

This is the only place in a chart where you can filter by an aggregate (SUM or COUNT).

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. If we use sum(total),is it going to calculate for all of the details or one particular group? I tried with sum(particular field)>0.It shows all of them because total always >0. I want to remove "PAID" group if that group total is 0.  Could you help me on possibility of using group variable filter?

Comment: It should filter by `each Group`. Maybe your `0%` doesn't mean that the TOTAL is actually zero? Maybe the total of your paid is actually `0.3%` but displays as `0%`?

Comment: yes, that may be the case. I have tried in the sum values expression as =iif(Sum(Fields!FieldName.Value)=0,Nothing,Sum(Fields!FieldName.Value)) ,it still shows the 0%.  I got this idea from this link https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d4f9c49c-35ce-462c-8478-ddd3f08c8b62/how-to-hide-datapoint-label-in-piechart-if-value-is-0?forum=sqlreportingservices.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Renu's approach (as in comments), just to elaborate, in order to suppress zero values (in data cells) use the IIF() function to return appropriate, i.e. right click the Data-Cell -> select *Expression* and enter something similar to the following expression::

```
    =IIF( Sum(Fields!columName.Value)=0, Nothing, Count(Fields!columName.Value) )
```

In case where you need to return a Boolean value (True/False), then use something similar to below:

```
    =IIF(Count(Fields!columName.Value)=0, False, True)
```